# Sum of series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty{-\frac{1}{2^k-1}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is the sum of the series $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty{\frac{-1}{2^k-1}}$?

Also, more generally, can we find $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty{\frac{-1}{c^k-1}}$ for some $c$?

Comment: Do you mean $(-1)^k$? If not, why include the minus sign?

Comment: @joriki: No.  I guess I just did it for correctness.

Comment: I don't understand -- correctness of what? In what sense would the simpler sum without the minus sign not have been correct?

Comment: @joriki: I guess it's pretty pointless to include the minus.  Unfortunately, the answers here correspond with it included.  I'll remember to simplify things more for future reference.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ignoring the negative sign, you're looking for

$$ {1 \over 2^1 - 1} + {1 \over 2^2 - 1} + {1 \over 2^3 - 1} + \cdots $$

but we have

$$ {1 \over 2^{jk} - 1} = {1 \over 2^{jk}} + {1 \over 2^{2jk}} + {1 \over 2^{3jk}} + \cdots. $$

If we rewrite the first expression using the second one, then your sum is

$$ \left( {1 \over 2^1} + {1 \over 2^2} + {1 \over 2^3} + \cdots \right) + \left( {1 \over 2^2} + {1 \over 2^4} + {1 \over 2^6} + \cdots \right) + \left( {1 \over 2^3} + {1 \over 2^6} + {1 \over 2^9} + \cdots \right) + \cdots $$

and $1/2^r$ appears $\tau(r)$ times, where $\tau(r)$ is the number of divisors of $r$. Therefore your sum is

$$ \sum_{r \ge 1} \tau(r) 2^{-r} $$

and this should allow you to compute it to any desired level of numerical accuracy fairly quickly. For example,

$$ \sum_{r=1}^{40} \tau(r) 2^{-r} = {27602812537 \over 17179869184} = 1.606695152 $$

and the error here is less than $\sum_{r \ge 41} r 2^{-r} = 84/2^{41} < 4 \times 10^{-11}$ since $\tau(r) < r$ for all $r \ge 3$.

Of course this method works when $2$ is replaced by any constant $c > 1$.

Comment: Very clever use of the geometric series (which I lectured about in my Calc II class yesterday)! For those algorithmically minded folks in the audience, what clever ways are there to find $\tau(n)$? We can muck about with properties given a prime factorization, but would that save us much time/computation? I'd be happy to break this off into my own question, if desired.

Comment: I'm not really a number theorist. But computing $\tau(n)$ in general would be at least as hard as primality testing, since $n$ is prime if and only if $\tau(n) = 2$.

Comment: Via [Wikipedia's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function) take on the subject, I played around with computing $\tau(n)$ in Sage on my poor little laptop. Things seemed to be faster if we went with $\Pi_1^n (a_i + 1)$ (where $n = \Pi_1^n p_i^{a_i}$ is the prime factorization of $n$) than the naive approach, but that may just be my computer and poor skills.

Comment: What's the "naive approach" here? To be honest, I would have called the approach you used the naive approach.

Comment: Fair enough. I had in mind just trial division. In (unoptimized) Python code, something like `sum(1 for i in xrange(1, n + 1) if n % i == 0)`.

Comment: Well, yeah, that is naive. Maybe my approach is semi-naive.

Answer (score 3):

[Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%201/%282%5Ek-1%29%20from%201%20to%20infinity) gives an explicit answer for c=2, approximately -1.6067, and an explicit mess for arbitrary c.

Answer (score 3):

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty  c^{-k}\left(1-\left(\frac{1}{c} \right)^k \right)^{-1} ;c>1 $$

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty c^{-k}  +\sum_{k=1}^\infty c^{-2k} +\sum_{k=1}^\infty  c^{-3k} \cdots = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty c^{-n k} $$

In the double summation written above note that ($s=c^{-1}$) , $s^l$ appears as many times as there are solutions to  $nk=l$ where $n,k,l\in \mathbb{N}$. Let $f(l)$ be the number of solutions, then

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty s^{n k} = \sum_{l=1}^\infty f(l) s^l ; s<1  $$

The coefficient $f(l)$ is studied in more detail in number theory as it appears in the square of the zeta function. $\zeta (s)^2 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{f(n)}{n^s}$

The $f(n)$ is called the [divisor function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function). So one way will be to write the series as a power series with the coefficients $f(n)$.

Other option is to use  Computer algebra, as Ross answered. Mathematica gives a closed form

$$\frac{-\text{Log}[-1+c]-\text{Log}\left[\frac{1}{c}\right]-\text{QPolyGamma}\left[0,1,\frac{1}{c}\right]}{\text{Log}[c]}$$

Answer (score 3):

It is the [Erdős-Borwein Constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erdos-BorweinConstant.html). (modulo a minus sign)